# How to read all the rows from an XLS file when sheet/section name is not provided in Go

Tags: excel, go, xls

I need to read all the rows from `.xsl` files in Go. Found this amazing [Excelize library](https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize) that would let me read from & write to XLSX/XLSM/XLTM files.

Unfortunately their [`GetRows()`](https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize/blob/820a314cfbcaa4d32401b0b6c67bf65f064483ec/rows.go#L24) requires **worksheet name**.

```
// Get all the rows in the Sheet1.
rows, err := f.GetRows("Sheet1")
for _, row := range rows {
    for _, colCell := range row {
        fmt.Print(colCell, "\t")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

In my case, each file will have differently named worksheet. So is there a way to just get all the rows of the  **defaulted/first worksheet**? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `f.WorkBook.Sheets.Sheet[0].Name` to get the name of the first sheet, where `f` is an `excelize.File`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    f, err := excelize.OpenFile("Book.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    firstSheet := f.WorkBook.Sheets.Sheet[0].Name
    fmt.Printf("'%s' is first sheet of %d sheets.\n", firstSheet, f.SheetCount)
    rows, err := f.GetRows(firstSheet)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    for _, row := range rows {
        for _, colCell := range row {
            fmt.Print(colCell, "\t")
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

With a toy Excel workbook with 2 sheets, I get the following output:

```
'Sheet1' is first sheet of 2 sheets.
1       2
```